# Overriding transaction propagation levels for methods having Spring's @transactional

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I have multiple methods in my codebase annotated with [Spring's `@transactional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) with different propgation levels (lets ignore the idea behind choosing the propagation levels). Example -

```
public class X {
    @Transactional(Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void A() { do_something; }

    @Transactional(Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void B() { do_something; }

    @Transactional(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void C() { do_something; }
}
```

Now I have a new use case where I want to perform all these operations in a single transaction (**for this specific use case only, without modifying existing behavior**), overriding any annotated propagation levels. Example -

```
public class Y {
    private X x;

    // Stores application's global state
    private GlobalState globalState;

    @Transactional
    public void newOperation() {
         // Set current operation as the new operation in the global state, 
         // in case this info might be required somewhere
         globalState.setCurrentOperation("newOperation");

         // For this new operation A, B, C should be performed in the current 
         // transaction regardless of the propagation level defined on them
         x.A();
         x.B();
         x.C();
    }
}
```

Does **Spring** provide some way to achieve this ? Is this not possible ?

- One way I could think of is to split the original methods

  ```
  @Transactional(Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
  public void A() { A_actual(); }

  // Call A_actual from A and newOperation
  public void A_actual() { do_something; }
  ```

  But this might not be as simple to do as this example (there can be a lot of such methods and doing this might not scale). Also it does not look much clean.
- Also the use case might also appear counter intuitive, but anyway let's keep that out of scope of this question.

Comment: Sounds like you need to take the `@Transactional` annotations off the method definitions and then create separate wrappers for each situation with the appropriate annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe the only option is to replace `TransactionInterceptor` via `BeanPostProcessor`, smth. like:

```java
public class TransactionInterceptorExt extends TransactionInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        // here some logic determining how to proceed invocation
        return super.invoke(invocation);
    }

}
```

```java
public class TransactionInterceptorPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor, BeanPostProcessor, BeanFactoryAware {

    @Setter
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(@NonNull ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        beanFactory.addBeanPostProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(@NonNull Object bean, @NonNull String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof TransactionInterceptor) {
            TransactionInterceptor interceptor = (TransactionInterceptor) bean;
            TransactionInterceptor result = new TransactionInterceptorExt();
            result.setTransactionAttributeSource(interceptor.getTransactionAttributeSource());
            result.setTransactionManager(interceptor.getTransactionManager());
            result.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
            return result;
        }
        return bean;
    }

}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class CustomTransactionConfiguration {

    @Bean
    //@ConditionalOnBean(TransactionInterceptor.class)
    public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor transactionInterceptorPostProcessor() {
        return new TransactionInterceptorPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

However, I would agree with @jim-garrison suggestion to refactor your spring beans.

UPD.

> But you favour refactoring the beans instead of following this approach. So for the sake of completeness, can you please mention any issues/shortcomings with this

Well, there are a plenty of things/concepts/ideas in spring framework which were implemented without understanding/anticipating consequences (I believe the goal was to make framework attractive to unexperienced developers), and `@Transactional` annotation is one of such things. Let's consider the following code:

```java
    @Transactional(Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void doSomething() { 
        do_something; 
    }
```

The question is: why do we put `@Transactional(Propagation.REQUIRED)` annotation above that method? Someone might say smth. like this:

> that method modifies multiple rows/tables in DB and we would like to avoid inconsistencies in our DB, moreover `Propagation.REQUIRED` does not hurt anything, because according to the contract it either starts new transaction or joins to the exisiting one.

and that would be wrong:

- `@Transactional` annotation poisons stacktraces with irrelevant information
- in case of exception it marks existing transaction it joined to as rollback-only - after that caller side has no option to compensate that exception

In the most cases developers should not use `@Transactional(Propagation.REQUIRED)` - technically we just need a simple assertion about transaction status.

Using `@Transactional(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` is even more harmful:

- in case of existing transaction it acquires another one JDBC-connection from connection pool, and hence you start getting 2+ connections per thread - this hurts performance sizing
- you need to carefully watch for data you are working with - data corruptions and self-locks are the consequences of using `@Transactional(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`, cause now you have two incarnations of the same data within the same thread

In the most cases `@Transactional(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` is an indicator that you code requires refactoring.

So, the general idea about `@Transactional` annotation is do not use it everywhere just because we can, and your question actually confirms this idea: you have failed to tie up 3 methods together just because developer had some assumptions about how those methods should being executed.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But you favor refactoring the beans instead of following this approach. So for the sake of completeness, can you please mention any issues/shortcomings with this

Comment: @him please check the UPD

Comment: Thanks. Eventualy everything boils down to pros vs cons