# Java Spring Number of database connections per thread

Tags: java, spring, transactions, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I was wondering whether we have a limitation on number of connection each Java thread can open to the database.
Because when I try to execute a transaction using `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` which I believe opens a new connection to the database, I get following error:

```
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool Connection is not available, request timed out after
```

Based on my search it seems that Hikari is not giving my thread a new connection.
and when I try to manually close the previous connection I no longer get this error.
How I close the current (previous) connection :

```java
c = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
c.close();
```

So what is the workaround? and if there is a limitation for number of connections per thread can I change this setting ?

Comment: There are no limitations per thread, only pool sizes. If the pool is exhausted you will get this exception. However the fact that you use certain code to close a connection makes me wonder why you are even messing around with connections yourself. It seems like you are opening double the amount of connections due to Spring opening and using them and you youself that is messing around with it.

Comment: @M.Deinum when we use ```Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW```  as transaction propagation type, It will create a new database connection and if the first transaction has dirty commits it's not usable that's why we're creating a new connection through using ```Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW```

Comment: I don't need to explain to me what `REQUIRES_NEW` entails. My concern is that when you are mangling the connection yourself you are already doing the wrong thing. Manually closing it is doing the wrong thing, as that will influence the current ongoing transaction.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring boot add below property in the application.property to define pool size

```
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle= 10 
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size= 100
```

Comment: I have these settings in my configuration, but it's for the whole Java threads.
What I meant is what is the limitation of connections per thread.
I mean thread which are responsible for handling user requests and are handled by the web container (Tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

> How I close the current (previous) connection :
>
> ```
> c = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource); 
> c.close();
> ```

didn't get that point, if you are using `spring-tx` why do not use it's `JdbcTemplate`? Moreover, make sure that you are closing connection in finally block:

```java
Connection c = null;
try {
  c = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
  ...
} finally {
  if (c != null) {
     c.close();
  }
}
```

or using try-with-resources:

```java
try (Connection c = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource)) {
   ...
}
```

in regards to `@Transactional(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` - [consider refactoring you code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72163950/overriding-transaction-propagation-levels-for-methods-having-springs-transacti/72165975#72165975).

---

UPD. The correct pattern to release DB connection acquired via `DataSourceUtils#getConnection` is following:

```java
try {
  c = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
  ...
} finally {
  if (c != null) {
     DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(c, dataSource);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll refactor my connection closing, but in general are you aware that we have any kind of limitation for number of db connection per thread ?
I mean Tomcat threads.

Comment: @MajidAbdolhosseini had never faced such issues before, however everything depends on the code, from my perspective using `@Transactional(Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` is bad idea - it acquires connection from connection poll for every nested call, thus you can't predict what pool size is required/sufficient.

Comment: So what is your suggestion?
Basically I have an exception which makes. the initial transaction dirty and it will not be usable. so that's why we're creating a new transaction using ```Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW``` and behind the scene it's creating a new connection

Comment: if you do not what to refactor the code, the estimation of connection pool size is `amount of threads * amount of "nested" transactions`, otherwise you will get a situation where thread is competing with itself for connection pool, for example, by default tomcat spawns up to 200 threads, that means connection pool size should be at least 400 - that is actually too much. And here we are not discussing the case where suspended transaction blocks new ones.