@Transactional not behaving as expected
I'm looking to implement a queue for MSTeams notifications, which are picked up from a database table and processed over a period of time and if the Spring scheduled method encounters an error during that process, a full rollback of the attempt is made and an attempt is recorded into our database to be tried later. I had a suggestion of trying to use @Transactional here, but i'm running into a few issues with the final behaviour.
My understanding is the default with @Transactional is to propagate that session to subsequent method calls within the marked method. To facilitate the requirement of persisting the attempt to the database, I created a new method to handle the error processing. This method was marked @Transactional(propogation="REQUIRES_NEW") and worked, but failed a code quality check. I've lost the full return, but this was the message:

"handleRetryCount's" @Transactional requirement is incompatible with the one for this method"

Following this, I moved that particular method to a new class (here called) TeamsNotificationHelper and referenced the method from the new helper.
Now what I'm seeing is, when an exception is thrown, the selected row from the database remains locked, and no instance of the application ever touches that row again.
EDIT: Should be noted as well, that the project runs as a Docker container inside a Kubernetes cluster. It's not just 1 instance of this application, it can be as high as 5. If there are concerns about the long sleep, this process is already in place elsewhere in other services and is to minimize pointless calls to the database.
AnimalSchedule
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


import java.util.Optional;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AnimalSchedule {

    @Autowired
    AnimalNotificationRepository animalNotificationRepo;

    //Code for our Teams calls - not the issue
    @Autowired
    TeamsNotificationService teamsNotificationService;

    @Autowired
    TeamsNotificationHelper teamsNotificationHelper;

    private static final String HOSTNAME = "HOSTNAME";

    // 1s between requests when running
    // 10s delay before starting after pod spins up
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000, initialDelay = 10000)
    @Transactional
    public void processTeamsNotification() throws InterruptedException {
        if (!isSchedulerEnabled()) {
            longSleep();
            return;
        }

        Optional<AnimalNotification> notification = animalNotificationRepo.findOldestUnsentNotification();

        notification.ifPresent(n -> {
            if(n.getPodName() != null && n.getPodName().equalsIgnoreCase(System.getenv(HOSTNAME))){
                //Allow different pod to pick up send attempt if last Pod tried and failed.
                return;
            }

            try {
                processNotification(n);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                teamsNotificationHelper.handleRetryCount(n, e);
            }

        });

        if (notification.isEmpty()) {
            longSleep();
        }
    }

    public void processNotification(AnimalNotification notification) {
        //Don't need to capture response, as replies here won't be possible
        teamsNotificationService.sendNotification(new TeamsNotificationRequest(
                notification.getTeamsInformationId().getName(),
                notification.getNotificationContent()));
        teamsNotificationHelper.markNotificationWithStatus(notification, AnimalNotificationStatus.COMPLETE, null);
        animalNotificationRepo.save(notification);
    }

    private boolean isSchedulerEnabled() {
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(EnvironmentVariables.NOTIFICATION_QUEUE_ENABLED) && queueStatusRepository.getStatus();
    }

    private void longSleep() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(60 * 1000L);
    }`

TeamsNotificationHelper
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Service
public class TeamsNotificationHelper {

    @Autowired
    AnimalNotificationRepository animalNotificationRepo;

    private static final String HOSTNAME = "HOSTNAME";

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void handleRetryCount(AnimalNotification notification, Exception e){
        if (e instanceof IllegalArgumentException){
            //Only rows with incomplete data will throw this exception so safe to fail and not retry
            notification.setRetryCount(Integer.parseInt(EnvironmentVariables.MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPT));
            markNotificationWithStatus(notification, AnimalNotificationStatus.FAILED, e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        notification.incrementRetryCount();
        if (notification.getRetryCount() >= Integer.parseInt(EnvironmentVariables.MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPT)) {
            markNotificationWithStatus(notification, AnimalNotificationStatus.FAILED, e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        notification.setPodName(System.getenv(HOSTNAME));
        animalNotificationRepo.save(notification);
    }

    public void markNotificationWithStatus(AnimalNotification notification, AnimalNotificationStatus status, String errorDetails) {
        notification.setCompletedTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        notification.setPodName(System.getenv(HOSTNAME));
        notification.setStatus(status);
        notification.setErrorDetails(errorDetails);
        AnimalNotificationRepo.save(notification);
    }

AnimalNotificationRepository
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface AnimalNotificationRepository extends JpaRepository<AnimalNotification, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ANIMAL_NOTIFICATION_QUEUE WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST) WHERE status = 'WAITING' AND retryCount < 3 ORDER BY createdTimestamp ASC", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<AnimalNotification> findOldestUnsentNotification();

}


It was my understanding that if a new transaction is opened during the processing of an existing transaction, the first is suspended until the new one is committed. After the second is committed control should be passed back to the initial transaction to complete. Is this correct?

What would be the proper way to handle the behaviour I've described, is this not a good idea in the first place?


Any help that can be provided here would be really appreciated, happy to add more detail where possible if needed.

remove @Transactional annotation from processTeamsNotification() method and move logic of processNotification() method to another service with @Transactional. You got caught in @Transactional trap: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72165975/3426309

Your method is flawed, when the if (notification.isEmpty()) { is true it should do nothing. Remove the longSleep as that will block the scheduler thread and never re-schedule. Next that in your processNotification method use saveAndFlush to eagerly trigger exceptions, else they will be thrown only after transaction commit which is after the execution of your scheduled method.
